# Tkinter fixed column size not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple program, in which I want to align text to either the right, or the left. For example:

```
|Test                      |
|                      Test|
```

My idea was to create a label for the text and put right aligned text in column 1 and left aligned in column 0.

```
from tkinter import *

labels = []
i = 0

window = Tk()
window.geometry('300x500')

def newlabel(t,align):
    global i
    label = Label(window,text=t)
    label.grid(row=i,column=align)
    label.columnconfigure(0,minsize=150)
    label.columnconfigure(1,minsize=150)
    labels.append(label)
    i += 1

newlabel('Test',0)
newlabel('Test',1)

window.mainloop()
```

however, the 'Test' on the right is not placed correctly: it is placed just next to the first 'Test'.

How can I change the code to place it fully at the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are calling `columnconfigure` on the wrong object. You should call that on the widget that contains the column, not the widget that is *in* the column. In your case you should be doing `window.columnconfigure(...)`

You might want to also give those columns weight (also with the `columnconfigure` method, setting the attribute `weight` to a positive integer), so that they grow and shrink to fit the window. If you do that you'll also want to set the `sticky` attribute when you add them to the column, so that they grow to fill their column.